# Prolog : Execute intersection of two arrays without using inbuilt functions (such as intersection, member)

Tags: arrays, prolog

I have executed the intersection of two arrays using intersection in prolog. How can I execute this manually without using 'intersection'?

```
intersection([],[],[]).
intersection(_,[], []).
intersection(List1, [Head2|Tail2], output):-
    \+(member(Head2, List1)), intersection(List1, Tail2, output).
intersection(List1, [Head2|Tail2], [Head2|output]):-
    member(Head2, List1), intersection(List1, Tail2, output).
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact, depending on the compiler used, it is possible to create a predicate to compute set intersection that is more efficient than the predefined predicate `intersection/3`. In SWI-Prolog, version 8.2.1, I've obtained the following results:

```
intersection1(A, B, I) :-
    setup_call_cleanup(
        dynamic('$elem'/1),
        ( maplist([X] >> assertz('$elem'(X)), A),
          convlist([X,X] >> retract('$elem'(X)), B, I)),
        abolish('$elem'/1)).

intersection2(A, B, I) :-
    setup_call_cleanup(
        dynamic('$elem'/1),
        ( forall(member(X,A), assertz('$elem'(X))),
          findall(X, (member(X,B), retract('$elem'(X))), I)),
        abolish('$elem'/1)).

test_intersection(N) :-
    M is 10*N,
    randseq(N, M, A),
    randseq(N, M, B),
    time(intersection( A, B, I0)),
    time(intersection1(A, B, I1)),
    time(intersection2(A, B, I2)),
    sort(I0, S),
    sort(I1, S),
    sort(I2, S).
```

Some tests:

```
?- intersection([1,3,4,7,8,9], [0,2,3,4,6,9], I).
I = [3, 4, 9].

?- intersection1([1,3,4,7,8,9], [0,2,3,4,6,9], I).
I = [3, 4, 9].

?- intersection2([1,3,4,7,8,9], [0,2,3,4,6,9], I).
I = [3, 4, 9].
```

Execution time for bigger sets:

```
?- test_intersection(10000).
% 20,992 inferences, 2.875 CPU in 2.875 seconds (100% CPU, 7302 Lips)
% 70,013 inferences, 0.016 CPU in 0.016 seconds (100% CPU, 4480832 Lips)
% 41,014 inferences, 0.016 CPU in 0.016 seconds (100% CPU, 2624896 Lips)
true.

?- test_intersection(20000).
% 42,053 inferences, 11.203 CPU in 11.196 seconds (100% CPU, 3754 Lips)
% 140,013 inferences, 0.031 CPU in 0.031 seconds (100% CPU, 4480416 Lips)
% 82,075 inferences, 0.031 CPU in 0.031 seconds (100% CPU, 2626400 Lips)
true.

?- test_intersection(40000).
% 83,948 inferences, 47.563 CPU in 47.645 seconds (100% CPU, 1765 Lips)
% 280,013 inferences, 0.078 CPU in 0.070 seconds (112% CPU, 3584166 Lips)
% 163,970 inferences, 0.078 CPU in 0.078 seconds (100% CPU, 2098816 Lips)
true.
```

As we can see, doubling the size of the sets, the execution times of `intersection1/3` and `intersection2/3` almost double as well [i.e., time complexity is O(n)], while the execution time of the predefined predicate `intersection/3` is approximately four times larger [i.e., time complexity is O(n^2)].

Of course, as already said, that will depend on the compiler used.

Comment: Well, if you want to use a "side-store" to perform the intersection in an imperative manner, it feels much cleaner to manipulate an indexed structure that is a term rather than manipulate the indexed Prolog database using `assert`and `retract`. In other words: SWI Prolog [dicts](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=bidicts) or [library(assoc)](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=assoc)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer: I just wanted to show that it is possible to implement a predicate for intersection that is more efficient than that predefined in SWI-Prolog. And, as far as I know, SWI Prolog dicts or library (assoc) are not always more efficient than using ```assert``` and ```retract``` [especially library(assoc) , whose operations have cost O(lg n)]. Any way, it would be very instructive see your efficient and cleaner implementation of intersection by using ```dicts``` and/or ```library(assoc)```.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach:

The idea is to to compare each element of one list with each element of the other list. If H1=H2 then we have an intersection, else, we don't. So, when intersection found put it in the new list, else, don't. We are using flatten to give back the final answer removing the empty brackets.

```
intersection([H|T],[H2|T2],List):-
    intersection1([H|T],[H2|T2],R),
    flatten(R,List).

intersection1([],_,[]).
intersection1([H|T],[H2|T2],[R|List]):-
    intersection2(H,[H2|T2],R),
    intersection1(T,[H2|T2],List).

intersection2(_,[],[]).
intersection2(H1,[H2|T2],[H1|L]):-
    H1=H2,
    intersection2(H1,T2,L).
intersection2(H1,[H2|T2],L):-
    H1\=H2,
    intersection2(H1,T2,L).
```

**Examples:**

```
?-intersection([12, 3, 9,4,1],[6,7,4,8],List).
List = [4]

?-intersection([6,4,8,2],[6,7,4,8],List).
List = [6, 4, 8]

?-intersection([12,6,4],[5,2,1],List).
List = []

?-intersection([12,6,4,7,88],[88,5,7,2,1],List).
List = [7, 88]
```